# Как добавить ссылку в меню только на одной странице

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, как я могу добавить ссылку в меню только на одной странице. Например имеем меню (Главная, О нас, Контакты). На всех страницах оно одинаковое, хочу чтобы на главной site.ru было = (Ссылка, Главная, О нас, Контакты).

Думал это реализовать на JS, но не знаю как. Не силен.

```
if (window.location.pathname == '/' || window.location.pathname == '/index.php') {
   document.getElementById("menu-main-navigation").appendChild(newLi);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

Сделать два разных меню, одно из которых будет отображаться на главной, а другое на всех остальных страницах. Вывод меню в `header.php` тогда будет выглядеть так:

```
if (is_front_page()) {
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu' => 'home-menu-name', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );
} else {
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu' => 'page-menu-name', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );
}
```

**Вариант 2:**

Если вы в шаблоне используете функцию `body_class()` для вывода css классов, относящихся к текущей странице, то на главной у тега `<body>` будет класс `home`. В редакторе меню добавьте нужному пункту, например, такой класс `home-only-item`, а в файл `style.css` вашей темы добавьте такое правило:

```
body .home-only-item {
  display: none;
}
body.home .home-only-item {
  display: block;
}
```

**Вариант 3:**

Можете использовать хук `wp_nav_menu_items` для добавления вашего пункта меню. Например, это можно сделать добавив такой код в файл `functions.php` вашей темы:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_my_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function add_my_menu_item( $items, $args ) {
  if (is_front_page()) {
    $items = '<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://example.com/">Ссылка</a></li>' . $items;
    return $items;
  }
}
```

**UPD:** Если пункт меню нужно выводить на другой странице (не на главной), то в вариантах 1 и 3 вместо функции `is_front_page()` следует использовать функцию `is_page()`, передавая в качестве параметра ID или slug нужной страницы.